# Excluding all domains with a specific beginning from Google search results

Tags: search, domain, translation, exclude

I’m using Google to check how a word is used in the websites of a particular language,
but results from machine-translated pages lead to lots of low quality translations,
so I’d really like to exclude them all.

For the Estonian language, for example, those addresses usually begin with est., et. or ee.
I’d really appreciate finding a way to exclude them.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your request, you may do that by using the `minus` operator:

```
search-terms -est.* -ee.*
```

See for example
[Google Search Operators](https://moz.com/learn/seo/search-operators).

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick!